# Dynamically loaded dll interface function returns usercontrol

Tags: c#

For a minor project I have created a basic interface which is used to create plugins. This interface has a function that returns a UserControl. However when this is called and the UserControl is added to a panel nothing shows in the panel (even if `.Show()` or `Visibility = true` is set). I had assumed that when the `assembly.CreateInstance()` is called this creates instances of any objects in the class.

Is this not the case? Is a `CreateInstance()` required to be called on all UserControls before they can be used in this way?

```
public interface IMyInterface
{
    System.Windows.Forms.UserControl GetConfigurationControl();
}
```

Implemented class in the dll:

```
public class myClass: IMyInterface
{
    return new myUserControl();
}
```

Loaded all dlls in the directory:

```
private void LoadPlugins()
{
 foreach (string file in Directory.GetFiles(Application.StartupPath+"/plugins/", "*.dll",       SearchOption.AllDirectories))
        {
            Assembly assembly = Assembly.LoadFile(file);
            var types = from t in assembly.GetTypes()
                    where t.IsClass &&
                    (t.GetInterface(typeof(IMyInterface).Name) != null)
                    select t;
            foreach (Type t in types)
            {
                IMyInterface plugin = (IMyInterface)assembly.CreateInstance(t.FullName, true);
                this.pluginsList.Add(plugin); //just a list of the plugins
            }
        }
    this.AddPluginUserControls();
 }
```

Add the user controls to a panel:

```
 private AddPluginUserControls()
 {
     foreach (IMyInterface plugin in pluginsList)
     {
          myPanel.Controls.Add(plugin.GetConfigurationControl());
     }
 }
```

I am aware of other full plugin architectures however this is more a learning application.
Thanks!

UserControl:

```
public partial class myUserControl: UserControl
{
    public myUserControl()
    {
        InitializeComponent(); // couple of labels, vs generated.
    }
}
```

Comment: your code looks ok - how is `myUserControl` implemented? can you show some code around it?

Comment: Just a normal UserControl with some labels at this stage.

Comment: Does clearing old controls in `AddPluginUserControls` help?  `myPanel.Controls.Clear()` before `foreach`

Comment: Tried as well but it doesn't seem to make a difference either.

Comment: @Mark: When adding multiple controls to the panel, ensure to set `Location` so the controls do not overlap. For example, by adding up the `Height` and set `Top` for every control.

Comment: @Joe, thanks. It happens even if there is only one UserControl added.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure two things
1. in default `myUserControl` constructor, InitializeComponent() is called which will instantiate and add your labels to the control.
2. Give some width and height to the user control before adding to panel.

Comment: InitializeComponent() is definitely called, but changing the height/width unfortunately doesn't change it showing.

Comment: You still dont see anything? Please update your code in question to show you've given width and height so that others dont suggest same. If you put breakpoint in user control's constructor - does it hit?

Comment: It does hit the breakpoints in the constructor for    InitializeComponent().

Comment: hmm then i think better you show implementation for usercontrol and also what is type of `myPanel`?

Comment: It's System.Windows.Forms.FlowLayoutPanel

Comment: OK - I don't see any more problem. Make sure panel's Size is greater then user control's size. It may be also possible you dont see anything because all background colors are same. Change the background color of panel and also in the user control' implementation.

Answer (score 0):

Right found it! It was an issue with using a System.Windows.Forms.FlowLayoutPanel and the UserControl having the DockStyle set to fill. Thanks for all answers!